# Bootstrap3 tabs execute "shown.bs.tab" on loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, the following event will execute only when someone click on the tabs. So, how should i make it execute when it loads the default active page and the active tabs is dynamic.

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
       // Do something
 });
```

[LinK bootstrap3 tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)
Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of that?

Comment: Trigger it with `$('#someTab').tab('show')`

Comment: Tab is shown, i want to draw pie chart after the tab is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clicking the active tab after it has loaded which should then trigger the shown.bs.tab function

```
$(".nav-tabs li.active a").click();
```

or maybe just using that info of the active tab to execute the code you want something like this

```
function doSomething(target) {
    // do something with the target here
    // not sure what you want to do?
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // this happens on clicking a tab
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        doSomething(e.target);
    });

    // this happens on page load
    doSomething($(".nav-tabs li.active a"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me test it.

Comment: doSomething is not executed until you click on the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking but there a few ways to trigger the `shown.bs.tab` event. You can click on the tab, trigger clicking a tab with jQuery (`.trigger('click')`) or use `.tab('show')`.

If you asking how to determine the active tab pane once the `shown.bs.tab` event occurs, it can be done like this..

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href"); // activated tab pane
});
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/UaQqzIFDfK

Comment: The problem I am facing is i have a ChartJs function to draw pie chart once the tab is loaded. I can do this after i click but not able to draw the chart while loading the page.

Comment: Can't you draw the chart once `shown.bs.tab` occurs

Comment: I can draw chart after shown.bs.tab occur which means click right ? but I want to draw with the default active tab while loading. (before clicking to any tabs)

Comment: How do you execute a function at the *end* of the `shown.bs.tab` event?

Answer (score 0):

HTML (tab which has to be opened on load):

```
<li role="presentation" class="active-on-load"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
```

JS:

```
// Event delegation

$('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function() {
  console.log('Shown');
});

// Show active tab on load (remove active class from li and add your custom class)

$('.nav-tabs > .active-on-load > a').tab('show');

// If you have dynamic tabs - this is just a test to check if shown event is fired on dynamic added tabs (yes - thanks to event delegation)

var id = 0;
$('#addnew').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="presentation"><a href="#newtab' + id + '" aria-controls="newtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">New tab' + id + '</a></li>');
  $('.tab-content').append('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="newtab' + id + '">New tab ' + id + '</div>');
  id += 1;
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/vgRXPB)

Comment: Let me test this.